# How to remove carriage return when setting environment variable using shell script?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I have a shell script which I use to set an environment variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
export USERNAME=user
export PASSWORD=password
java -jar loader.jar
```

The problem is when I access the environment variable values it has an additional carriage return character at the end. I think this is because I create the shell script in windows and use it in a UNIX system. Is there a way to set the environment variable without adding this extra character?

Comment: why not delete them? eg https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1017

Comment: Or run `dos2unix` on the file before running it.

Answer (score 0):

got it fixed with a .gitattributes
adding *.sh text eol=lf in the .gitattributes fixed the problem for me.
Thank you everyone for your support